# Copy interrupted and difficulties to take it over by relaunch with cp -u or rsync

Tags: linux, macos, rsync, cp, gnu-parallel

I have a huge data to transfer between 2 macOS (1.3 TB).

Unfortunately, my copy from mac1 to mac2 (by mounting the concerned directory of mac1 on mac2 as network directory), the copy with '`rsync`' (used with `parallel` command) has been interrupted (855 GB has been copied on 1.3 TB for all the content).

Since this incident, I can't take over correctly the missing rest of what has not been copied.

I tried (on macOS 10.15.4 Catalina) :

```
parallel -j32 rsync -az {} /Users/home_henry_from_astro/ ::: /Volumes/henry/*
```

and

```
parallel -j32 /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/cp -urp {} /Users/home_henry_from_astro/ ::: /Volumes/henry/*
```

In both case, the copy seems to not be achieved, the command with `cp -u` doesn't say anything, same thing for `rsync -az`, except some errors of permissions which are not critical, at least I think.

I check regulary the size of the directory `/home_henry_from_astro/` but size doesn't increase, always the same size : `855 GB`

What does it happen ? How could I circumvent this issue which seems to be a hanging in the copy process ?

**EDIT :** I provide below more informations to debug this hanging :

Here the results of a : `$ ps aux | grep cp`

```
sh-3.2# ps aux | grep cp
root             39911  26.8  3.9  7914992 2603432 s004  R    10:05PM 264:46.62 /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/cp -urp /Volumes/henry/Phd_2019_2020 /Users/home_henry_from_astro/
root             39915  24.1  4.0  7857356 2661576 s004  U    10:05PM 280:13.09 /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/cp -urp /Volumes/henry/Projets_info /Users/home_henry_from_astro/
root             39848   0.0  0.0  4605780  15244 s004  S+   10:05PM   0:15.34 perl /usr/local/bin/parallel -j32 /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/cp -urp {} /Users/home_henry_from_astro/ ::: /Volumes/henry/COPIE_Stage_Incomplete_lors_de_la_copie_de_kawito_vers_astro ...
```

It is really weird since I have a running flag '`R`' on the first process but I don't know other codes like '`S+`' or '`U`' for the other processes

What do they mean  ?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you'll enable the `ssh` service on the "remote" Mac and run `rsync` in proper client/server fashion. This is far far more efficient than mounting a remote filesystem.

Nevertheless, let's assume you're still mounting the remote filesystem. Simplify the command and see what's happening here. I've removed `-z` because it's ignored when copying between directory points that appear to be in the local filesystem, and added `-v` to see what's going on. You might need to add another `-v` to get additional output

```
rsync -av /Volumes/henry/* /Users/home_henry_from_astro/
```

You've copied 800+ GB of data already. The `rsync` process has to skip all of that. Now because you've used the `-a` (archive) flag it can skip files based on size and time. But it has to retransfer *in entirety* any file that has either a different size or timestamp. Not just the parts that are changed, but the entire file. If this is a large file it's going to take quite a while to copy. (This is where you can gain if you can run one `rsync` on each end of a network connection, as then only changed blocks need to be retransferred.) If you're watching, you can use the `--progress` flag to see what's going on, but don't use this flag if you're writing to a log file

```
rsync -av --progress /Volumes/henry/* /Users/home_henry_from_astro/
```